# How to Save text in EditText after calling Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have 2 Activity A and B, in Activity A I have 1 EditText and 1 Button. The Button is use for calling Activity B. I just wondering, when the user input some text in EditText in first time, then user calling Activity B, After that Back to Activity A (A > B > Then Back to A) can I still have user input  Any Help is needed Thank you :D

Here my code for Activity A (CreateData is Activity A)

```
public class CreateData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button buttonAdd;
    private EditText edNama_sma;
    private String nama;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_data);
        edNama_sma     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama_sma);
        buttonAdd      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttom_add_koordinat);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        nama  = edNama_sma.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttom_add_koordinat:
            Intent c = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(c);
            finish();
        }
    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

        edNama_sma.setText(edNama_sma.getText());

    }
}
```

Comment: currently what's happening?

Comment: @HamidShatu : when i back to Activity A from B, the EditText is empty

Comment: Set nama as static..it may work...or and if u won't use finish () den on backkey press u can get ur previous efittext..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `onResume()` method and inside this method set the value of `name` as text of `EditText` named `edNama_sma`.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

    edNama_sma.setText(nama);

}
```

So, whole activity class should be look like

```
public class CreateData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button buttonAdd;
    private EditText edNama_sma;
    private String nama;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_data);
        edNama_sma     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama_sma);
        buttonAdd      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttom_add_koordinat);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        nama  = edNama_sma.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttom_add_koordinat:
            Intent c = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(c);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        edNama_sma.setText(nama);

    }
}
```

Comment: please, first carefully read my answer then math your update with my answer. I think you will understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: then your mean is set nama = edNama_sma.getText().toString(); and set nama to edNama_sma.setText right?

Comment: All this won't work because the activity is being finished when ActivityB is started, so when it is recreated the text that was in the edittext will have disappeared.

Comment: But you have called finish() when starting activityB. Therefore activityA will be destroyed, and when it is recreated OnCreate will be run and the variable nama will be null. You need to stop calling finish, or store the data in the activity's shared preferences or (worse option) make nama static. finish() destroys the activity and all of its non static variables.

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds oh...I don't why I have overlooked the `finish()` method that he called. Thanks for the concern. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ndr_sd remove the `finish()` method called after `startActivity(c)`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call finish when you start the other activity. Then the original activity will stay in the activity stack and the data in the edit text will still be populated.
Otherwise you should use SharedPreferences to store any temporary data you need to retain when you leave an activity. Sometimes if the device rotates it can wipe the contents of input views, in which case you need to save and reload them using SharedPreferences.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html